# Finding an adjacency matrix whose cube's diagonal is equal to a given vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, adjacency-matrices

How can I find all binary matrices $A$ such that $A^3$ is a non-negative, integer square matrix and

$$\mbox{diag}\left(A^3\right)=b$$

for some given vector $b$? 
Is there a way to characterize all the solutions?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  What is the motivation?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo,
This problem actually stems from its graph interpretation as suggested below.
I'm trying to characterize all the graphs (with a given number of vertices) that share the same triangle-distribution over the edges, i.e. that share the same diagonal of A^3 where A is the adjacency matrix.

Comment: Why must $B$ be positive rather than nonnegative? Do you only care about the diagonal of $A^3$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, $B$ can be nonnegative.
And Yes, only the diagonal of $A^3$ (which stands for the number of triangles that each vertex participates in)

Comment: That means there are only $n$ constraints, rather than $n^2$. I believe you should edit your question.

Comment: Thank you @RodrigodeAzevedo, I've edited the question, I think it's much harder now though.

Answer (score -2):

A is a matrix with the same eigenvectors as B and with eigenvalues that are the cube roots of B's eigenvalues

Comment: That's correct, but not helpful. The difficulty is hidden in the word "binary".

Comment: I wonder if the responders point isn't that you may be able to generate all cube roots reasonably efficiently and then just look through them.   Possibly there is even only one reasonable choice for the eigenvalues, as e.g. you need the positive root of the largest.

Comment: @michael I doubt so. First of all, even if $B$ is diagonal with distinct eigenvalues, there are $3$ cube roots for each eigenvalue and hence $3^n$ matrix cube roots. And, moreover, you can make similar considerations for the problem "does this matrix have a square root with nonnegative entries?", and yet this is a difficult problem: as far as I know, finding a complete characterization is still an open issue.